# Notify all dynos via broadcast?

Tags: heroku

is there a way to notify all dynos with a broadcast? I would like to notify the web nodes about a configuration change, so they can adjust to the new configuration without a restart. I understand that broadcasts should generally be implemented with a third party mechanism, but i feel this is a bit overengineered for the seldom times i want to do such a broadcast. Is there any simple way?

Thanks,
Otto

Comment: What kind of configuration change? Is this a change to some file that's part of your git depo? If so it feels like the more 'heroku way' to notify all dynos would be to commit the config file and push.

Answer (score 0):

You could use built-in postgres listen/notify http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-notify.html